# R Shiny- Filter based on first selection

Tags: r, shiny

I'm writing a shiny app to display a table based on two filters (product & rate). 
Second filter selection list should base on the first filter selection.

i.e, if I select A from product column filter, the rate column filter should only display "good" and "medium". 
(Note: this is a sample data actual data has about 100 categories)

```
data_test = data.frame(ID = c ("1","2","3","4","5"),
                       product = c("A","B","C","A","C"),
                       rate = c("good","medium","bad","medium","bad"),
                       cust = c(1,2,5,1,6))
```

Currently I am using the DT package. Can someone please help me to achieve this using DT package.

The code I currently use is as below.

**Server.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

data_test = data.frame(ID = c ("1","2","3","4","5"),
                       product = c("A","B","C","A","C"),
                       rate = c("good","medium","bad","medium","bad"),
                       cust = c(1,2,5,1,6))

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

    output$table <- renderDataTable({ 
        data_test        
    },
    filter = 'top',
    rownames = FALSE)    
})
```

**ui.R**

```
library(shiny)
if (!require("DT")) install.packages('DT')
library(DT)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Product"),


                  dataTableOutput("table")


))
```

Comment: Isn't your code doing this already? At least with your sample data it does what you are asking

Comment: Not really. For example, when I select "A" from product filter, it displays good and medium in the output table but, when I click on the rate column filter it displays all three categories.

Comment: Oh, I get it now. It would be better to edit your question to say rate column filter instead of just rate column

Comment: Thank you. Sorry for the confusion. I edited the question.